# SQL or SQLAlchemy expression to get nearest upcoming TV episodes

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have the following Flask-SQLAlchemy models, but the SQL tables should be easy to figure out to those who don't know SQLAlchemy:

```
from myapp.api import db

class Show(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128))

class Episode(db.Model):
    title = db.Column(db.String(256))
    airtime = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('show.id'), primary_key=True)

    show = db.relationship('Show', backref=db.backref('episodes'), lazy='joined')
```

I'm trying to get the nearest upcoming episode (and its show) for every show, but I can't figure out the SQL to do that.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of `min()`, `GROUP BY`, etc. but I'm getting the feeling I need to use sub-queries to do this.

I use SQLite for what it's worth.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want an [tag:SQL] or [tag:SQLalchemy] answer?

Comment: I will be using SQLAlchemy in the end, but I'd probably have to figure out how to do it in SQL first.

Answer (score 0):

This should return last Episode for each show:

```
SELECT * FROM Show JOIN Episode ON Show.id=Episode.show_id
WHERE airtime=(SELECT MAX(airtime) FROM Episode WHERE show_id=Show.id)
```